# Best File I/O option in java?

Tags: java, file, file-io

I am new in java and now learning the File io . but i am very confused about the io as there are many objects to deal with it (FileReader, FileWriter, BufferedReader, BufferedWriter, FileInputStream, FileOutputStream ... and may be there are more).

I want to know that what is the most efficient process for File io(What should i use ?).i don't want any encoding. i want just processing text files.
Any simple example code will be greatly helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: You could try the different options... usually BufferedReader wrapping a FileReader is best

Comment: Consider using the new IO API in java. [`NIO`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html).

Comment: i saw the NIO and found it a little heard (my bad !)(couldn't understand the codes)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First important point to understand and remember:

- **Stream**: sequence of **bytes**.
- **Reader/Writer**: sequence of **characters** (**Strings**)

Don't mix them, don't translate for one to another if not necessary, and always specify the encoding.

Some quick recipes:

To **read** a file as a sequence of **bytes** (binary reading).

```
new FileInputStream(File f);
```

The same adding buffering:

```
new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(File f));
```

To **read** a file as a sequence of characters (**text** reading).

```
new FileReader(File f); // ugly, dangerous, does not let us specify the encoding

new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(File f),Charset charset);  // good, though verbose
```

To add line-oriented buffering (to read lines of text)

```
new BufferedReader(  ... someReader ... );
```

To output/write is practically the same (output/writer)

Comment: really a helpful answer. one more thing, what is the Charset? and would be the value of charset ?

Comment: Its will match the character encoding your files use.  If in doubt `UTF-8` is a popular choice.

Comment: @palatok : a file is in itself a sequence of bytes. To translate it to text, you must specify the charset encoding, the most used today are UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1. Also read this obligatory link: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 5):

Simple thumb of rule.

Text - Readers / Writers
Binary - InputStream / OutputStream

You can read more at [Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html)

Comment: There is a gotcha though, `FileWriter/FileReader` are useless as they don't allow you to specify encoding.

Comment: but i heard that FileReader, FileWriter use default encoding or something like that , so it's a little tricky. correct me if i'm wrong

Answer (score 0):

**Reading**

Following will allow you to read line by line

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileLocationTxt));
```

**Writing**

Following will allow you to write line by line/part by part

```
DataOutputStream ds = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(newLocation));
```

As for your question, there is no BEST option. Even in here, you can see we have to use 2 or more at once (look at the constructors. They accept other reader/writer or inputStream/outputStream.

The best option depends on what you really want to do

Comment: Actually first is for text files while second you put if for binary files

Comment: is there any way without using the FileReader() ? i saw some people discouraged it.(also don't understand why?)

Comment: @palatok: FileReader is used to read characters. If it is used along, it could be bad. But not always. There might be some reasons where that is sufficient. BufferedReader is used to read more than 1 character at a time. It can got methods to read line by line, which is really helpful. They also improve the performance. That is the simple explanation.

Comment: @Cratylus: Yes, including text files.